From any element of $\mathrm{SO}(8)$, can we always find one corresponding $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ element?
I first recap the relation between $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ and then raise my question concerning $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(8)$. Given any traceless hermitian matrix $H$, we can always write it using Pauli matrices as
$$
H=a_1\sigma _1+a_2\sigma _2+a_3\sigma _3\equiv \vec{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma}.\tag1
$$
If we choose $U\in \mathrm{SU}(2)$, we have $\mathrm{tr}(UHU^\dagger)=0$, that is, $UHU^\dagger$ is still traceless hence can be represented as $\vec{a}^{\prime}\cdot \vec{\sigma}$. Moreover, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{a}^{\prime}\cdot \vec{a}^{\prime}&=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left[ \left( \vec{a}^{\prime}\cdot \vec{\sigma} \right) \left( \vec{a}^{\prime}\cdot \vec{\sigma} \right) \right] 
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left( UHU^{\dagger}UHU^{\dagger} \right) =\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left( H^2 \right) =\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\left[ \left( \vec{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma} \right) \left( \vec{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma} \right) \right] =\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus $\vec{a}^{\prime}$ and $\vec a$ can be connected by some O(3) elements, denote it as $O$. Moreover, since when $U=I$, $\vec a ^\prime=\vec a$, the O(3) element is the identity matrix with determinant $1$. Since the determinant is a continuous function, we thus know $O$ is further SO(3). Furthermore, but also more technical, for any SO(3) element, we can find one corresponding SU(2) element in the sense of how $\vec a$ is transformed into $\vec a^\prime$.
Now, let's proceed to SU(3) and SO(8). Any three-dimensional traceless hermitian matrices can be expanded by $8$ Gell-Mann matrices. With the same reasoning as above, for any SU(3) element, we can find one corresponding SO(8) element. My question is, is the inverse also true? That is, for any SO(8) element, can we also find one corresponding SU(3) element?

For what it's worth, one can imbed $SU(3)\subseteq U(3)\subseteq SO(6)\subseteq SO(8)$.

It seems the answer is negative: given one arbitrary $\mathrm{SO}(8)$ element, we cannot always find one corresponding $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ element in the sense of the transformation of the coefficients before Gell-Mann matrices. The dimension of the $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ group is $3^2-1=8$ while the dimension of the $\mathrm{SO}(8)$ group is $8\left( 8-1 \right) /2=28$.
